# Chrome does not show broken images

Tags: google-chrome

I just noticed that my Chrome (Version 60.0.3112.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)) does not show a broken image. I am able to see a broken image in other borwsers.

This html script shows a fictious page and image

```
This line is before the broken image.
<img src="http://www.doesnotexistabc.com/missing.jpg" >
This line is after the broken image.
```

This is a jsfiddle link you can test it out.
https://jsfiddle.net/mxgavahr/1/

Is this something a user can configure? Or something is wrong with my browser?

I am using a Windows machine. I need to fix this issue because I would like to know an image is missing in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open bug in Chrome tracker about it https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=753724.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, maybe reset all chrome settings? If thats not the case, use ALT text

Comment: alanforts, thanks for helping me! I dont want to do a reset at this moment, because I have so much configured/installed on my chrome. I would like to reset all settings if I am sure there are no other reasons. Best.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome started doing this for me today as well. The broken image is treated as if the img element itself has no size. A declared width collapses down to nothing except for any styles, such as border and padding. The code below makes three small squares, each 22px by 22px.

```
<img width="500" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 10px" src="http://www.doesnotexistabc.com/missing.jpg">
<img width="500" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 10px" src="http://www.doesnotexistabc.com/missing.jpg">
<img width="500" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 10px" src="http://www.doesnotexistabc.com/missing.jpg">
```

Comment: Dumarest, your approach clutters the code. I still feel that this situtatoin may be caused configuration, extensions, or malware???